# Inline Error in Emacs for C,C++

Tags: emacs, compiler-construction

How can I enable or get inline error message in Emacs as other IDE support.

That is, if I remove a variable declaration, other IDEs will show the red mark in front of all uses of that variable.

Is there a way to get on type error highlighting in Emacs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is Flymake (http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FlyMake)